# Separate Button action and segue action

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uistoryboardsegue

I have to push a new segue when a button is pressed. But i also have an action attached to it that needs to be triggered before the segue is pushed.

Can you tell  me how to separate them from each other? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make the segue directly from one view controller to the other instead of connecting it to the button. Give it a meaningful name.

Then, in your button's action method, perform whatever you need to do first, then perform the segue using your view controller's `performSegueWithIdentifier:` method, using the meaningful name you chose earlier.

From your comments, it seems like you're trying to set properties on the view controller that is about to appear from your segue. If this is the case, you should implement `prepareForSegue:`, and use `segue.destinationViewController` to get a pointer to the view controller that is about to appear.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried doing what you told, but still the view is pushed first and the action is performed after. Here's the coding i'm using - 
`code`
-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        
        
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    
    viewController.query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", search.text];
    
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"search" sender:self];
        
    [viewController release];
    
}
`code`

Comment: Well, that won't work! When the segue is performed, the OS makes a new view controller for you, so the one you've made in your code does nothing. It looks to me like you should be setting those properties in `prepareForSegue:` instead.

Comment: I implemented both solutions you told. Things seems to be a bit fine, but now the app is crashing. I tried adding this - 


-(IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
        
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"search" sender:sender];
        
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"search"]) {
        
    
    
    ViewController *viewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    
    viewController.query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", search.text];
    
    [viewController release];
    }

    
}

Comment: And this is the exception thrown in output box: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewAnimationState tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x918d4e0'

Comment: Don't release the view controller. You didn't create it, so don't release it. That will be causing your new error as the controller will be deallocated.

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice it at all. Thanks a lot mate. It worked flawlessly.

Comment: @jrturton Hello! Currently I'm in the same situation as the OP. After the button's work is done, do I have to call the `performSegueWithIdentifier:` or does it run automatically?

Comment: @Isuru You call it yourself, as I say in the answer