# How to make segue wait for function to complete on button press?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a swift application that grabs some gps data on one view controller and then passes that data to another view controller.

My current approach involves a button, where a user will enter some data, hit this button, and then the button should perform two actions, calculate the gps routes, AND perform a segue to the next view controller.

However, I can't seem to get the segue to wait for my calculations to complete before going to the next screen. If I land on the second view and then press back, and then press the button again, the data will show up on the second screen, but I can't seem to get it to work right away.

I followed this question: [Separate Button action and segue action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123131/separate-button-action-and-segue-action) and still am having trouble

I am a complete noob to swift so I apologize if this question is trivial

`FirstViewController.swift`:

```
....
@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!
var routeArray = Array<Array<MKRoute>>()
var distanceArray: [CLLocationDistance] = []

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segue_to_table"{
        if let destination = segue.destination as? SecondTableViewController{
            destination.routeArray = self.routeArray
            destination.distanceArray = self.distanceArray
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ....
    calculateButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getRoutes(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func getRoutes(button: UIButton){
   locationArray = set of calculated MKMapItems
   calculateRoute(index: 0, distance: 0, routes: [], color: UIColor.green)

    locationArray = []
    locationArray = set of other MKMapItems (different route essentially)
    calculateRoute(index: 0, distance: 0, routes: [], color: UIColor.red)
}

func calculateRoute(index:Int, distance: CLLocationDistance, routes: [MKRoute], color: UIColor){
    let request: MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.source = locationArray[index]

    request.destination = locationArray[index+1]

    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
    request.transportType = .walking

    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {(response:MKDirectionsResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let routeResponse = response?.routes{
            var distVar = distance
            var routeVar = routes

            routeVar.append(routeResponse[0])
            distVar += routeResponse[0].distance

            if index + 2 < self.locationArray.count{
                self.calculateRoute(index: index+1, distance: distVar, routes: routeVar, color: color)

            }
            else{
                self.routeArray.append(routeVar)
                self.distanceArray.append(distVar)
            }

        }else if let _ = error{
            //alert
        }


        })


      }
```

Comment: Don't trigger the segue directly from the button; link the segue to the view controller object in the storyboard and then trigger the segue programmatically via `performSegue` when you are ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks good as-is, so the problem is in one of the parts you omitted. I see two possibilities:

**1) Your "segue_to_table" segue is linked directly to `calculateButton` in the storyboard.**

If that's the case, it's performing the segue immediately *and* calling `getRoutes()` at the same time. The solution is to remove that segue and make a new manual segue.

To do this, control-click the little yellow circle with a white square inside it in the first view controller and drag to the second view controller. Give it an identifier and you're all set.

**2) The omitted "long task" involves something asynchronous.**

If that's the case, `getRoutes()` will *start* the asynchronous task, then immediately trigger the segue before it completes.

How to fix it depends on the specific asynchronous code, but most likely you'll want to look for a "completion" callback and put your call to `performSegue()` there.

---

**Update for new code**

You've definitely got a problem with asynchronous code, which is complicated by recursion. Aside from the problem of when to segue, it looks like you've also got a *race condition*: in `getRoutes()` you start `calculateRoutes()` twice, so both will be operating on the same `routeArray` and `distanceArray` in unpredictable order.

To clean this up, you need to realize that `calculateRoute()` is an asynchronous function and make it behave like one. You want something to happen when `calculateRoute()` is finished with its asynchronous calls, so add a parameter to give it its own completion callback, and call it when all the asynchronous work is done:

```
func calculateRoute(index:Int, distance: CLLocationDistance, routes: [MKRoute], color: UIColor, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // ...
    directions.calculate(completionHandler: {(response:MKDirectionsResponse?, error: Error?) in
        if let routeResponse = response?.routes {
            // ...
            if index + 2 < self.locationArray.count{
                self.calculateRoute(index: index+1, distance: distVar, routes: routeVar, color: color, completionHandler: completionHandler)
            } else {
                self.routeArray.append(routeVar)
                self.distanceArray.append(distVar)
                // done, call completion handler
                completionHandler()
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Now when you call you `calculateRoute()` you pass it a function to call when it finishes. It makes one asynchronous call to `calculate()` after another until there are no more, then it calls your `completionHandler` and terminates. I should mention it's not super safe to have it operate on an external `locationArray` (what happens if some other process changes that array while `calculateRoute()` is running?) but that's a separate issue.

Now you want to use `calculateRoute()` to calculate two routes and append them in sequence to your `routesArray` and `distanceArray`. Because you don't know which will terminate first, you can't just call them at the same time. You call the first one, then call the second from the first's `completionHandler`. And since you want to perform the segue after *both* are done, you call that from the *second* completion handler. So it looks like this:

```
func getRoutes(button: UIButton) {
    // ...
    // start first asynchronous calculation
    calculateRoute(index: 0, distance: 0, routes: [], color: UIColor.green) {
        // ...
        // finished first calculation, start second one
        self.calculateRoute(index: 0, distance: 0, routes: [], color: UIColor.red, completionHandler: {
            // finished second calculation, now segue
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_to_table", sender: self)
        })
    }
}
```

Note that we're using the [trailing closure syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102) here, which is neat but can be confusing if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: it might be the 2nd one as I have implemented the 1st part. I will try and get back with you to see if thats the problem

Comment: @user3470987 A lot of the CoreLocation functions are asynchronous, so if you're using GPS it's a strong possibility. If you have you trouble, add that code to your question for a more specific answer.

Comment: I think I understand the completion handlers now, but my problem is that `getRoutes()` calls another function `calculateRoutes(...)` which has a recursive calling function, so I'm not sure where I would put the handler...

Comment: @user3470987 It's difficult to say without seeing the code. Can you edit your question to include the code from `getRoutes()` and `calculateRoutes()`?

Comment: Ok, I added the code, I'm not sure how I can wait for `directions.calculate(completion handler...)` to finish before preceding

Comment: @user3470987 You have a pretty complicated situation but I think I've got it sorted out. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: interesting, I kinda cam across a solution where I called another identical calculate route within the completion handler and that seemed to work (and no issues with different routes colliding) but it was messy and I would like to add a lot more routes. I tried implementing your approach but Im not sure what to do when I recursively call the function within calculates completion handler

Comment: @user3470987 I think I see what you mean. I left that line out for neatness, but there's an important change there. When you recursively call `calculateRoute()` you just pass the `completionHandler` along. Since it's not forking, the handler will only get called once at the end of the sequence. I edited my answer with the change.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, just prevent the segue with should perform segue,

Return false if you function is not ready yet. 
Once your function is ready, call the perform segue again and return true

```
func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (identifier == "mySegueIdentifier") {
        return isComplete
    }
    return true
}
```